# Android | Java | How to update content of TextView depending on received answers for http-requests which are sent to php-server every second?

Tags: java, android, http

I have a `TextView` which should be updated every `updateTime` (for example, 1000) milliseconds. Text for updating is retrieved through `HTTP`-connection from Web server . Web server supports two major requests: request for getting and request for setting values in `MySQL` database.

`PHP`-script interacts with the only table in the only database that has structure as shown below :

`ID (shortint)  | deviceState (integer)`

In order to lessen output internet traffic,  variable names and possible values in requests are replaced according to table below:

```
{
"REQUEST_TYPE "  - > "q" : ("REQUEST_FOR_GETTING_DEVICE_STATE" - > "0",
"REQUEST_FOR_SETTING_DEVICE_STATE" - > "1");
"ID" -> "w" : integer;
// table stores only one device with (ID) 1
"DEVICE_STATE" - > "e" : integer;
}
```

Examples of requests:

1) "http://wave-rp-bot.esy.es/server.php?q=0&w=1" - retrieves state of device with (ID) 1 which is stored in a database.

2) "http://wave-rp-bot.esy.es/server.php?q=1&w=1&e=0" - sets state of device with (ID) 1 which is stored in a database as 0.

There is no significant difference If "`GET`" or "`POST`" type of requests is used. However,  the last one is preferred in terms of security. How can I do this If it's started and stopped by pressing a `Button`-element.

As an answer I would prefer to get `Android` project where necessary behaviour is implemented.